# CXX Library for Finite State Machines/Automata with Run-time Operations

Tags: c++, boost

I'm looking for a CXX library that implemented finite state machines (or automata) with run-time operations over state machines?

In SageMath, there is a module [Finite State Machines](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/combinat/sage/combinat/finite_state_machine.html) that is exactly what I'm looking for.

I looked though the following libraries. But in all of them, the state machine should be specified in the code.

- [Finite State Machines (ex-Boost.FSM)](https://github.com/Lastique/fsm)
- [TinyFSM](https://github.com/digint/tinyfsm)
- [The Boost Statechart Library (boost::fsm)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/statechart/doc/index.html)
- [The Boost Meta State Machine (MSM)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/msm/doc/HTML/index.html)

But I would like to `add_state(s)`, `delete_state(s)`, `add_transition(s1,s2,input,output)`, `delete_transition(t)`
or something like these, **at run-time**.

Is there any CXX library available?

Answer (score 0):

Qt's QStateMachine can do that.

First, create a state machine.

```
QStateMachine sm;
```

And then, create states.

```
QState *s1 = new QState();
QState *s2 = new QState();
```

You can add transitions to the state as follows:

```
//                Event source  Event        Transition to state
s1->addTransition(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), s2);
```

Finally, add the state machine to the states as follows:

```
sm.addState(s1);
```

That means you can create state machines, states, and transitions dynamically.

Here is a document:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/statemachine-api.html